# How do I filter sensitive Django POST parameters out of Sentry error reports?

Tags: django, heroku, error-reporting, sentry, sensitive-data

To quote the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/error-reporting/#django.views.decorators.debug.sensitive_post_parameters):

```
@sensitive_post_parameters('pass_word', 'credit_card_number')
def record_user_profile(request):
    UserProfile.create(user=request.user,
                       password=request.POST['pass_word'],
                       credit_card=request.POST['credit_card_number'],
                       name=request.POST['name'])
```

> In the above example, the values for the pass_word and credit_card_number POST parameters will be hidden and replaced with stars (**********) in the request’s representation inside the error reports, whereas the value of the name parameter will be disclosed.
>
> To systematically hide all POST parameters of a request in error reports, do not provide any argument to the sensitive_post_parameters decorator:

```
@sensitive_post_parameters()
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

As a test, I added the following code to my Django 1.6 application:

views.py:

```
@sensitive_post_parameters('sensitive')
def sensitive(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        raise IntegrityError(unicode(timezone.now()))
    return render(request, 'sensitive-test.html',
          {'form': forms.SensitiveParamForm()})
```

forms.py:

```
class SensitiveParamForm(forms.Form):
    not_sensitive = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    sensitive = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
```

When I submit this form via `POST`, I can see the values of both fields (including `sensitive`) clear as day in the Sentry report.

What am I doing wrong here?  I'm using Django 1.6 and Raven 3.5.2.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Also when `DEBUG` is set to False?

Comment: Yes, it should be set to `False`.

The exact line in my settings file is as follows:

    DEBUG = (os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG_MODE', 'off') == 'on')

And currently, in the Heroku environment,

    DJANGO_DEBUG_MODE = off

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out that this stemmed from a bug in Django itself!

If you haven't changed [`DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER) in your `settings` file, you get the default filter of [`SafeExceptionReporterFilter`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/813ded775d2491bc12b55b8dbbb4a2e591e9dd15/django/views/debug.py#L119).

If you've used the [`sensitive_post_parameters`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#django.views.decorators.debug.sensitive_post_parameters) decorator, this will result in your calling `SafeExceptionReporterFilter`'s [`get_post_parameters`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/813ded775d2491bc12b55b8dbbb4a2e591e9dd15/django/views/debug.py#L148) method:

```
 def get_post_parameters(self, request):
        """
        Replaces the values of POST parameters marked as sensitive with
        stars (*********).
        """
        if request is None:
            return {}
        else:
            sensitive_post_parameters = getattr(request, 'sensitive_post_parameters', [])
            if self.is_active(request) and sensitive_post_parameters:
                cleansed = request.POST.copy()
                if sensitive_post_parameters == '__ALL__':
                    # Cleanse all parameters.
                    for k, v in cleansed.items():
                        cleansed[k] = CLEANSED_SUBSTITUTE
                    return cleansed
                else:
                    # Cleanse only the specified parameters.
                    for param in sensitive_post_parameters:
                        if param in cleansed:
                            cleansed[param] = CLEANSED_SUBSTITUTE
                    return cleansed
            else:
                return request.POST
```

The problem with the above is that while it *will* correctly return a `QuerySet` with the sensitive `POST` parameters set to `CLEANSED_SUBSTITUTE` (`'********************'`)...**it won't in any way alter `request.body`.**

This is a problem when working with Raven/Sentry for Django, because it turns out that the [`get_data_from_request`](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-python/blob/4dbe43be6d0a37645b2b9f64f86d4bdc67692e81/raven/contrib/django/client.py#L52) method of Raven's `DjangoClient` first attempts to get the request's `POST` parameters from `request.body`:

```
def get_data_from_request(self, request):

  [snip]

    if request.method != 'GET':
        try:
            data = request.body
        except Exception:
            try:
                data = request.raw_post_data
            except Exception:
                # assume we had a partial read.
                try:
                    data = request.POST or '<unavailable>'
                except Exception:
                    data = '<unavailable>'
    else:
        data = None

 [snip]
```

The fastest fix turned out to just involve subclassing `DjangoClient` and manually replacing its output with the cleansed `QuerySet` produced by `SafeExceptionReporterFilter`:

```
from django.views.debug import SafeExceptionReporterFilter
from raven.contrib.django.client import DjangoClient


class SafeDjangoClient(DjangoClient):

  def get_data_from_request(self, request):
    request.POST = SafeExceptionReporterFilter().get_post_parameters(request)
    result = super(SafeDjangoClient, self).get_data_from_request(request)
    result['sentry.interfaces.Http']['data'] = request.POST
    return result
```